# deque.tcc error: expected primary-expression before '>' token

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, tbb

When compiling my project with **OpenCV** and **TBB** on **Linux** (**Ubuntu 12.0.4**, **GCC 4.6.3**, **Eclipse**), the console went into error that is reported with /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/deque.tcc. The error is `expected primary -expression before '>' token`, which is in the include line, and the include file is opencv's `cv.h` and `objdetect.hpp` which include `<deque>`.

I don't know why the system library will be reported with errors.

(OpenCV version is old, about 2.0, and I am building a shared library C++ project).

The lines near the include line:

```
//file beginning
#ifndef _FEATUER_EXT_HPP
#define _FEATUER_EXT_HPP

#include "opencv/cv.h" //cv.h includes objdetect.h and further include <deque>

enum FEA_TYPE{
    FEA_LBP256  = 0,
    FEA_LBP59   = 1,
    FEA_HIST10  = 2,
    FEA_SIFT128 = 3,
    FEA_SURF64  = 4,
    FEA_HAAR144 = 5,
    FEA_GABOR_SIFT256= 6,
    FEA_GABOR_SURF128= 7,
    FEA_GABOR120     = 8,
    FEA_GABOR160     = 9,
    FEA_GABOR240     = 10,
    FEA_GABOR320     = 11,
    FEA_SURF128      = 12,
    FEA_SIFTC128     = 13,
    FEA_GABOR_HAAR192= 14,
    FEA_CSLBP_8U     = 15
};
```

Comment: Show some lines around `#include <cv.h>` and `#include "objdetect.hpp"`.

Comment: @timrau ok. see the edit.

Comment: I assume it is the gcc version that doesn't support c++ 11. I will upgrade it and try again...

Answer (score 0):

mrmoment,

Without looking at the code it is not easy to diagnose, but I can tell you when I have seen these problem before with TBB, the culprit is usually a #define that does a textual substitution in a template definition.  I would try preprocessing the file (-E) and look at the location in error in the pre-processed output.

I hope this helps a bit.

Regards,
Chris